# Find the shortest module path to a function/class

Tags: python, module, package

I need to automatically find the shortest module path to a function/class, knowing its longest module path.

For instance, the following path to a class in the `torch` module:

```
torch.nn.modules.linear.Linear()
```

Should be reduced to the (also valid) path:

```
torch.nn.Linear()
```

Ideally, it should also be able to detect when even shorter paths are possible when specific imports have been made, such as:

```
import torch.nn as nn
nn.Linear()
```

How could I automatically find such shortcuts ?

Comment: I usually use the document at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html

Comment: Right, but I need to automate this as I'm automatically parsing pytorch models and I'm only given the longest path to functions/class and need to display them in their shortest form.